Proof of Hopf-Calabi strong maximum principle (in the barrier sense).
I read a maximum principle in Zuoqin Wang's lecture notes on Riemann geometry (see Lec 24)
http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~wangzuoq/Courses/24S-RiemGeom/index.html
Definition of "in the barrier sense":
Let $f$ be a continuous function defined on $(M, g)$.

If $g \in C^2(U)$ is defined in a neighborhood $U$ of $p$, and
$$f(p) = g(p), \quad f(q) \leq g(q), \quad \forall q \in U,$$
then we call $g$ an $\textit{upper barrier function}$ of $f$ at $p$.

If for any $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists an upper barrier function $g_\varepsilon$ of $f$ at $p$, such that
$$\Delta g_\varepsilon(p) \leq c + \varepsilon,$$
then we say $\Delta f(p) \leq c$ $\textit{in the barrier sense}$.


The maximum principle states that
(Hopf-Calabi strong maximum principle) Let $\Omega \subset M $ be a connected open set. Suppose $\Delta f\le 0$ in M in the barrier sense, and $f$ has an interior minimum, then $f$ is constant on $\Omega .$
The usual Hopf maximum principle seems not working here. Can anyone provide a proof or any relevant resources about it?

Here are two suggestions: 1) I believe Calabi's original paper explains it well 2) The Hopf-Calabi maximum principle is needed for the Cheeger-Gromoll splitting theorem. I suggest searching for expositions of this theorem to see if they either prove the maximum principle or give a reference to a proof. One such paper is "An Elementary Proof of the Cheeger-Gromoll Splitting Theorem" by Eschenburg and Heintze.
